# Свернуть все папки

Tags: javascript, html

Есть что то вроде панели быстрого доступа. В ней списком много папок. Рядом с каждой папкой кнопка, при нажатии на которую появляется выпадающее меню, с содержимом папки, при нажатии ещё раз - собирается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML код **кнопки** открытой папки:

```
<button class="spoticon-chart-down-16 RootlistItemFolder__arrow RootlistItemFolder__arrow--is-rotated"></button>
```

HTML код **кнопки** закрытой папки:

```
<button class="spoticon-chart-down-16 RootlistItemFolder__arrow"></button>
```

К классам раскрытых **папок** всегда добавляется

```
RootlistItemFolder--is-expanded
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть код на JS, что бы все раскрытые папки свернулись?

P.S. Может быть поможет:
Код, блокирующий вообще открытие папок.

```
    function waitForElement(els, func, timeout = 100) {
    const queries = els.map(el => document.querySelector(el));
    if (queries.every(a => a)) {
        func(queries);
    } else if (timeout > 0) {
        setTimeout(waitForElement, 300, els, func, --timeout);
    }
}

waitForElement([".LeftSidebar__section--rootlist .SidebarList__list"], ([sidebar]) => {
    function shrinkFolders() {
        for (item of sidebar.childNodes) {
            // Only folder item has this class so we don't have to filter by folder first
            if (!item.classList.contains("RootlistItemFolder--is-expanded")) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // Find "expand folder" button and click it to shrink folder
            const button = item.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
            button.click();
            return;
        }
    }

    new MutationObserver(shrinkFolders)
        .observe(sidebar, {childList: true});
});
```

P.P.S. В комментариях предложили добавить побольше кода, но там его так много, что выходит каша (ну или я просто не умею правильно копировать HTML). Так что, наверное, лучше скриншотами.

Закрытой папки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открытой папки (всё, что после красной линии - уже вне папки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121136/discussion-on-question-by-fiftyfour7250---).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать в более читабельном виде с async

```js
// Это оставляем для поиска всего блока
function waitForElement() {
  return new Promise((s) => {
    (function wait() {
      let queries = document.querySelector('.LeftSidebar__section--rootlist .SidebarList__list')
      queries ? s(queries) : setTimeout(wait, 300)
    })()
  })
}

// Запуск всего этого
void async function () {

  // Ждем нахождения всего блока
  const sidebar = await waitForElement()

  // Функция закрытия кнопок
  function shrinkFolders() {

    // [Вариант 1] 
    // Проходимся по всем элементам
    for (let item of sidebar.childNodes) {
      // Проверяем открыта ли папка
      if (!item.classList.contains("RootlistItemFolder--is-expanded")) {
        continue
      }
      // Если открыта и есть кнопка закрываем по одной кнопке
      (item = sidebar.querySelector('button')) && item.click()
      // !!! Вот здесь был указан "return", но при закрытии всех он не нужен
    }

    // [Вариант 2]
    // Смотрим все кнопки с классом + --is-rotated и сразу все закрываем
    // [...sidebar.querySelectorAll('.RootlistItemFolder__arrow--is-rotated')].forEach((e) =>  e.click())

  }
  shrinkFolders()

  // Отслеживание изменений - когда появились новые элементы
  new MutationObserver(shrinkFolders)
    .observe(sidebar, { childList: true })

}()
```

Comment: Первый вариант всё ломает, всё зависает. А второй очень даже работает, только из него нужно было удалить "Отслеживание изменений - когда появились новые элементы", иначе это блокирует открытие папки, и выходит тоже самое, что и с кодом из вопроса. Получается, что сейчас код выглядит так: https://pastebin.com/vwN9pcAk и всё работает как надо, но с каждым новым запуском приложения сворачивается лишь по одной открытой папке, а надо что бы все.

Comment: Ещё, если нет никакого варианта изменить `[...sidebar.querySelectorAll('.RootlistItemFolder__arrow--is-rotated')].forEach((e) =>  e.click())` так, что бы закрывало не по одной, а сразу все папки, зная примерное количество папок - можно просто вписать кучу строк, и тогда всё вообще работает один в один, как нужно. https://pastebin.com/LHjAjtxA

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 Вот я и писал: "Определить без доступа к сайту очень сложно". Там явно что-то происходит в момент изменения приложения, а как это узнать?:( Второй вариант с множеством одинаковых строк, как минимум странный - ведь одна строка и должна закрыть все кнопки, а они вновь откуда-то появляются. Значит приложение что-то мгновенно меняет, и это необходимо отслеживать непосредственно в браузере

Comment: Ну вообще огромное тебе спасибо, сейчас ведь всё работает просто идеально, я больше двадцати этих строк вписал, и хватит даже с запасом. Большое, искреннее спасибо, за то что не лень было разбираться, код писать. И если вдруг интересно - это не совсем сайт, это клиент Спотифая, на который установлена spicetify-cli - утилита для модификаций, благодаря ей и доступ к html коду, и собственно для неё же и расширение это на js. Так что если опыта ради нужно - можешь зарегистрировать Спотифай, создать там папки, установить клиент, установить spicetify-cli. Но нужно ли... Ведь всё уже сделано))

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 я понял что Спотифай, но я этим не пользуюсь, потому и не знаю что там и куда установлено. А вообще надо было эту процедуру установки в вопрос написать. Тем у кого стоит было'б легче сориентироваться. Когда сам видишь что там происходит, гораздо легче разобраться.